# How to prevent page refresh upon form.trigger('submit')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following code which works well when triggered by the user clicking on the form's submit button:

```
            // load dashboards when filter form is submitted
            $('div.active form.filter-form').submit(function (e) {
                // get submitted values
                submittedData = $(this).serializeArray();
                getDashboardURL();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

However whenever I try to trigger the form submission in the snippet below, it results in the page refreshing:

```
            // trigger reload of dashboard
            $('select.filter').change(function () {
                $('select#'+this.id).val($(this).val());

                $('div.active form.filter-form').trigger('submit');

            });
```

How can I prevent the form submission (triggered by the select change event) from refreshing the page?

Comment: seems okay to me. do you have any error in browser console?

Comment: in first code block you have used  e.preventDefault();  so, it restrict to submit by default, but in second it submit by form "submit"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put `return false` on your markup of form.

```
<form onsubmit="function(); return false;">
```

Otherwise changing the button type to `"button"` instead of `"submit"` also should work.